# Dynamically change textures in three js for imported gltf model

Tags: three.js, gltf, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

No matter what I do, I cannot get a texture to update after importing a GLTF model using react-three fiber.

```
const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF("/glb4.glb");
const newtexture = useLoader(TextureLoader, "texture1.jpg");
newtexture.flipY = false;
```

Now I can do

```
let newmaterial = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial({ map: newtexture});
```

to import it into the scene with

```
<mesh
    geometry={nodes.Body_Front_Node.geometry}
    material={newmaterial}
  />
```

However it results in a grey material without the texture. Even modifying the original gltf material with the new texture gives the same result.

Is there a way to update the texture of a gltf mode dynamically? Here is the full codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/github/Mazzz-zzz/fabrigen/main?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js

Answer (score 0):

You can try rendering `meshStandardMaterial` under `mesh` as follows and provide `newmaterial` as `map` prop to `meshStandardMaterial`. That worked for me. -

```html
  <mesh geometry={nodes.Body_Front_Node.geometry}>
    <meshStandardMaterial map={newmaterial} />
  </mesh>
```